# What URL rewriting rule should I write to retrieve a var in the URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom page template that behaves as an archive : its URL is `www.mysite.com/test/`. "Pretty links" are enabled. I need to add it a number, such as `www.mysite.com/test/1234`.

The purpose is to retrieve this number and serve the corresponding archive.

I've been using a variable named `num`, declared as follows in the `functions.php` :

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_register_qv' );
function my_register_qv( $qvars ){
    //Add query variable to $qvars array
    $qvars[] = 'num';
    return $qvars;
}
```

Still in `functions.php`, here is the rule I wrote :

```
 function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('test/^[0-9]*$' => 'index.php?pagename=test&num=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Finally, in my template's code, here is how I retrieve the variable :

```
//$maxnum is the default value
$num = get_query_var('num', $maxnum);
```

But when I call a URL like this one : `www.mysite.com/test/1234`, the "1234" value is not retrieved by the `get_query_var()` function. Instead, I am given the default value.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your rewrite rules function, it should be

```
function num_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'test/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=test&num=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'num_rewrite_rule' );
```

**Reference**

[`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

**NOTE:** Always remember to flush your permalinks by visiting **Settings - Permalinks **

Comment: Thanks but in this case I still get the default value...

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: yes but the result is still the same

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules after adding this by going to **Settings - Permalinks - Save Changes**

Comment: thanks !!!! I forgot this detail !!!! it works perfectly

Comment: Just visiting the permalinks settings page flushes rules, you don't have to re-save.